# Hostinger & Vercel hosted on 1 domain

Tags: wordpress, vercel, headless-cms

I have Wordpress hosted on Hostinger and a domain over there as well. I use the Hostinger setup as a headless cms and I have nextjs setup using WPGraphQL to query wordpress.

My question is, as i have a domain on Hostinger making my wordpress login:

https://www.exampledomain.com/wp-admin

Is it possible to use this domain on vercel and have the same domain:

https://www.exampledomain.com/

Any help on how I could achieve this would be great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Hostinger specifically, but I've used domains purchased from other places like Namecheap and Squarespace with Vercel. There's an option to use your own domain even if it's not hosted on or purchased with Vercel.

That being said, I'm actually doing the same thing as you for a client in a few weeks, so if I beat you to it, I'll confirm whether it works or not.